# Send mails to multiple users with looping using mailx and output from another file

Tags: mailx

Project scope: Locking few users and sending them email that has to be automated.
Issue: the mailx part isn't working as I need help on how to input the options for mailx.
DB server: AIX 7.x

I have a file that has the below:

```
    alter user x1 account lock;   
    alter user x2 account lock;
```

I have to use the x1,x2.. and send these user individual email using mailx.

Part of my script is:

```
    for i in $(cat Test_lock_users.log)   
    do 
    print mailx -c manager@abc.com -s "WARNING - $ORACLE_SID User account Locked" "manager@xyz.com $i@xyz.com"  
    done
```

Korn shell script as stated above in #2. This is on AIX 7.x server

I got the output as given below and no email sent to the address.

```
    mailx -c manager@abc.com -s WARNING - $ORACLE_SID User account Locked manager@xyz.com x1@xyz.com

    mailx -c manager@abc.com -s WARNING - $ORACLE_SID User account Locked manager@xyz.com x2@xyz.com
```

No error message either. Its just gave the output and how to execute/run the mailx with x1, x2 inputs?

Comment: `while read _ _ i _; do mailx -c manager@abc.com -s "WARNING - $i User account Locked" "manager@xyz.com $i@xyz.com"  
    done <Test_lock_users.log`

Comment: It there are no users in the log file mail shouldn't be sent.